# Application Level Resources XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

How do I create an application level resources in XAML? I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 app btw.

Below I have a rectangle, I want to create a resources that can be used to change the colour of the rectangle when tapped:

```
<Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           Height="100" 
           Stroke="Black"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Width="100"
           x:Name="pad1"
           Tap="pad1_tap"           
 />
```

I have read some similar posts that say to use:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Resources Here !-->
</Application.Resources>
```

... but there is no object under the name 'Application' within my application. When trying to use 'Application.Resources' I get an error stating: The member Resources is not recognized or accesssible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Application object is in your `app.xaml` file. But it's useful only if you want your resource to be shared by the whole application. If you need it only in one page, you can declare your resource in the `PhoneApplicationPage` element:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <!-- your resource -->
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to import a `mscorlib` library and then refer to your resources using `StaticResource` keyword, like so:

```
<Application
    x:Class="AppClass"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">

    <Application.Resources>
        <sys:Int32 x:Key="Test">80</sys:Int32>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Usage:

```
<Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           Height="100" 
           Stroke="Black"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Width="{StaticResource Test}"
           x:Name="pad1"
           Tap="pad1_tap"           
 />
```

Comment: It's the same for wp8. You can generate a sample wp8 application in your visual studio and check the source code.

Comment: Actually this In32-thing doesn't work for me with VS13 U1 and a WP8 project :(

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

That works well for my case: `<x:Int32 x:Key="intKey">9001</x:Int32>` :)